# React Native Stripe - Network request failed

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

For an app I am making, I want to make the user pay 10EUR via a paymentscreen in React Native with the help of Stripe. Unfortunately I keep stumbling upon errors when I try to test it with the 4242 card of stripe.
It only occurs when I click on the 'pay' button.

I get the error saying:

length=0; index=0

I do also have a warning stating network request failed and i'm pretty sure it is linked to it.

Could you help me out?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CardField, useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

const PaymentScreen = () => {
  const { confirmPayment } = useStripe();
  const [key, setKey] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        Alert.alert(res.clientSecret);
        const intent = res as {clientSecret: string};
        setKey(intent.clientSecret);
    });
}, []);

const handlePayment = async () => {
  try {
      const { error } = await confirmPayment(key, {
          paymentMethodType: 'Card',
      });

      if (error) {
          Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
      } else {
          Alert.alert('Payment successful!');
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Network request failed:', error);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Network request failed. Please check your internet connection.');
  }
};

  return (
    
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Enter Card Details:</Text>
      <CardField
        style={{
            height: 100,
            width: '100%',
        }}
        postalCodeEnabled={false} // Adjust based on your requirements
        placeholders={{
          number: 'Card Number',
          expiration: 'MM/YY',
          cvc: 'CVC',
        }}
        onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
          // Handle card details change if needed
        }}
      />
      <Button title="Pay" onPress={handlePayment} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default PaymentScreen;
```

And this is the piece of code from the back end side:

```
import express from 'express'
import Stripe from 'stripe'

const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_XXX', {
    apiVersion: '2023-10-16',
    typescript: true,
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1000,
        currency: 'eur',
    });

    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    })
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running'));
```

[here is a printscreen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCkYl.png)

I get the error on both my physical and virtual device.

Could you help me understand the problem and show me a way out?
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar issues reported in the stripe-react-native [repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Astripe%2Fstripe-react-native%20length%3D0%3B%20index%3D0&type=issues) and they are all related to server-side code. Have you checked your Stripe Dashboard [Logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) to confirm if the PaymentIntent creations were successful?

Comment: Hmm indeed, I have some errors coming from the logs, I'll try to fix it on the server side! Thank you :) !